# massive-js limit columns from result

Tags: javascript, node.js, massivejs

The following code returns id, title and content fields. I need only id and title.

```
  db.laws.search({columns: ["title", "content"], term: req.params.text}, function(err,laws){
    res.contentType('application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(laws));
  });
```

I need and an equivalent of "select id, title from laws where...". I can not find anything in the [docs](http://massive-js.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I would like to avoid a for loop to filter out unwanted columns, it is less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the massive.js code, you have not option for remove `id` from result row in `search` method.
My advice is use [`Inline SQL`](http://massive-js.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simple_queries/#the-simplest-query-inline-sql)